# How to map apache to use an index file inside another directory in www/html/ without reflecting on url

Tags: .htaccess, apache-2.4, localhost

```
 Apache version: 2.4
 OS: Ubuntu 14.04
```

I am not sure whether I wrote the heading correctly. My index file is located at some directory (say `/var/www/html/new/` ) rather than the default apache root. I want apache to load the index file from this directory when I type `localhost` or my IP onto the address bar. I cannot use this (`/var/www/html/new/` ) directory as the document root, since I have dependency files in `/var/www/html/`. I want apache to load the index file in the directory `/new/` without altering the url. I mean when I type `localhost` It should load that index file and the url should not be `localhost/new/`

Is there any way to do this? Can it be made possible using `.htaccess` file? I am pretty new to this stuff. It would be helpful if someone could explain in simple terms.

UPDATE

I just read this is possible using apache url rewrite. Can somebody explain how to do this? Does it use htaccess?

Comment: Sounds like you need to change the DocumentRoot in you Apache config to `/var/www/html/new/`. Did you you try that?

Comment: @Gmck I tried that. But as I have mentioned in question, I have some dependency files `/html/` folder itself. So the index file in `/new/` doesn't load properly.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have the index file in `/var/www/html/new/` (e.g. `/var/www/html/new/index.html`) you could just do this with a symbolic link so your index file also appears in `/var/www/html/`

For example, first become the Apache user (so any files you create have the correct permissions):

```
sudo -s -u www-data
whoami
$ www-data
```

Create a symlink:

```
ln -s /var/www/html/new/index.html index.html
```

See what you get:

```
ls -l /var/www/html/

total 4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data   28 2016-01-19 14:36 index.html -> /var/www/html/new/index.html
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data 4096 2016-01-19 14:25 new
```

Comment: I tried this now. But it doesn't seem to be working. Instead of showing the index page it simply shows the directory listing :(

Comment: My example above assumes you've got index.html as (one of) the values for the DirectoryIndex directive. If you've got index.php (for example) you should adjust the ln command e.g. ln -s /var/www/html/new/index.php index.php